# Why does GetLastError return 0 when it's called in a DLL library?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Assume I'm having a DLL library with this pseudo-code:

```
var
  LastError: DWORD;

procedure DoSomethingWrong; stdcall;
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    FileStream := TFileStream.Create('?', fmCreate);
  except
    on EFCreateError do
      LastError := GetLastError; // <- why does GetLastError return 0 here ?
  end;
end;
```

Why does [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function return 0 when it's used in a DLL library like shown above ? Is there a way to get the last error code for this case ?

Comment: What would you expect it to be? GetLastError returns the last error that a Windows API function generated and there is only one slot, so anything the Delphi exception handling system might do with the Windows API might reset or change that value. Normally, custom exceptions for which the value of LastError is relevant wrap the value in a custom property.

Comment: You have to call it immediately after an API call. You aren't doing that. Try doing it right after a failed CreateFile. Bottom line is that your code is invalid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your call to `GetLastError` returns `0` because there are other APIs called after `CreateFile` returns, and your exception code executes.

The error code returned by `GetLastError` a thread local variable and is shared between all code that runs in your thread. So in order to capture the error code you need to call `GetLastError` immediately after the failed function returns.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) explains it like this:

> Functions executed by the calling thread set this value by calling the
>   **SetLastError** function. You should call the **GetLastError** function
>   immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call
>   will return useful data. That is because some functions call
>   **SetLastError** with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code
>   set by the most recently failed function.

If you are using `TFileStream.Create` then the framework doesn't give you an opportunity to call `GetLastError` at the suitable moment. If you really want to get that information you will have to call `CreateFile` yourself and use a `THandleStream` instead of `TFileStream`.

The idea there is that with `THandleStream` you are responsible for the synthesis of the file handle which you pass to the constructor of `THandleStream`. That gives you the opportunity to  capture the error code in case of failure.

Comment: All of this sounds reasonable, but I'm still wondering, what resets the error. It must be something between caller and the library since if you run that code in a VCL application, it returns proper error code (though you're of course right that I should have call it immediately after `CreateFile` by myself).

Comment: I'm not very motivated to analyse that. It's clear how you are meant to use GetLastError.

Comment: My bad, I should have phrase this question differently. Never mind. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This is actually caused by a bug in the RTL that I reported to QC way back in 2004 ([QC #8680](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=8680)) and closed as fixed in 2010.

Comment: @Remy, that's the answer what I was looking for (not for the question as it's phrased). Thanks!

Comment: @TLama - No. David's answer is the correct answer. The TFileStream class is an abstraction, it doesn't guarantee to preserve the last error or anything. In fact it uses the last error to raise an exception with an appropriate message. Besides I wonder how does the RTL have a hand on resetting the error, all it does is to call FormatMessage with the last error value. If it did have a bug, I wonder why would the behavior be different for an executable and a library?

Comment: @Sertac, I know it's correct. I just phrased this question wrong; I wanted to know what resets the last error. It's some API call between the caller and the library. And the resolution that it's an unintended behavior make sense to me.

Comment: I don't think that the bug that Remy reported really is a bug. I don't think it's fair to expect the RTL to preserve last error for that long. I'd probably make sure that the error code was put into a field of the exception that was raised. If the framework would have called RaiseLastOSError, that would have happened. Sadly it doesn't use EOSError.

Comment: @TLama - I agree with David, besides, Remy's report doesn't tell anything about what resets the last error.

Comment: I really don't think that you can't expect `GetLastError` to mean anything in an exception handler. You could have executed a bunch of finally blocks in between API error and exception catch.

Comment: @TLama The FormatMessage call is still there. And I see nothing that calls `SetLastError` after it.

Comment: Yes, the `EOSError` would be a good option for the `TFileStream` implementation (and I'm actually using it in a real implementation of my modified file stream already). @Sertac, it does, there's a note *"the error code is getting reset while the Message property is being formatted"*, so it will be that `FormatMessage` function call (don't have a debugger by hand now). The question is then, why it's called only for DLL libraries (I'm just curious).

Comment: @TLama It's not just called in a DLL. It's always called. Even in XE3.

Comment: @David, if it was I wouldn't get the last error of the `CreateFile` call in the exception handler of a VCL application.

Comment: @TLama Well, I can see it in the code. It's just sitting right there.

Comment: @TLama - That doesn't mean anything, it's not the RTL that's setting the last error. What you wonder is what I mentioned in my comment as a reason to be suspicious of an RTL bug. The simple fact is, the RTL does never explicitly call SetLastError. It's purely an implementation detail in the OS that, when FormatMessage is called in a dll some code path that goes to IsProcessorFeaturePresent leads to a SetLastError call.

Answer (score 3):

At a higher level, the real issue with this code is that it is mixing models. You're attempting to create or open a file with one system (VCL TStream system) but you're testing for errors produced by a different system (Win32 API).

The only way you can rely on the Win32 GetLastError result is if you are calling Win32 functions yourself. Why? Because that's the only way to ensure that there are no other calls to Win32 functions between your Win32 function call and your call to GetLastError.  Every Win32 API call has the potential to (re)set GetLastError.

Even though VCL sits on top of Win32, there is plenty of opportunity for some other Win32 API call to occur between when the error occurs and when the exception reaches your handler. Even if things worked fine today, some future change in the VCL implementation could easily disrupt the happy coincidence that is the current situation.

The best way to avoid this "hang time" where the data you need is vulnerable to being overwritten is to have the GetLastError value captured as close to the point of failure as possible and incorporated into a property of the VCL exception object. This would all but eliminate the risk of some innocent interloper between your exception handler and the point of failure obliterating the GetLastError global state.